# Orbital Period problem not printing anything?

Tags: printing, physics

I am *brand* new to Python. I have an orbital period problem where I need to write a program that calculates the altitude an object would have to have for a given orbital period T in a preformatted Jupyter notebook from my professor. So far I have the following in a code cell

```
G = 6.67E-11

M = 5.97E24

R = 6371.0E3

T = float(input("Enter the desired period T: "))

h = ((G*M*T)/(4*pi**2))**(1/3)-R

print("The altitude of the satellite is", h, "meters")
```

but I don't know how to get this program to produce the altitude. I hit 'run' in Jupyter notebooks once, and a cell popped up saying "Enter the desired period T" which promptly disappeared when I clicked elsewhere. This has got to be an outrageously simple issue but I'm *not* seeing it. I'd be grateful for any help!

Comment: Why not fill in the prompt instead of clicking elsewhere? If you don't give it input, how is it supposed to work?

Comment: Valid question! I think I was just surprised it worked - I can't say why I clicked in the code cell. The prompt's not reappearing, though. Any ideas?